# How can I affect Opacity of an image whilst hovering a div?

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

I'm so so close to acheiving what I want... but I'm wondering if I've hit the limit of what is possible with css.

If you navigate to http://host17.qnop.net/~gjcwebde/ecocamel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=28&Itemid=49

We have a product slider. I'm trying to get it so that..

1) products start at 100% opacity on load.
2) hover over a product.. and the one you are hovering over stays at 100% opacity, **the others all go to say 0.5 opacity** (dim down).

I have ALMOST achieved this with css. Yo can see it working, except, when you hover over the description that pops up... the active image goes back to 0.5 opacity. Is it possible to control the opacity of this image, whilst hovering over the popup description? I really really hope so! Failing that... how might I acheive this with js? Looked at some on here, but none really apply to my situation. Hope I've given enough information for you to understand. Cheers!

Comment: you probably hover on the image and not on the container that contains both the image and the popup description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I picked up your html and put it in a fiddle. Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/hMW8N/

Anyway, this is all you basically need. I'm over specifying with these selectors, but I'm doing it so you can better understand.

```
#slider-list-stick-1:hover .slide-index{
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); //ie
}

#slider-list-stick-1 .slide-index:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); //ie
}
```

Comment: YES YES YES!!! This is the one! Thank you mate, you don't know how long I've been working on tat :) I'll take a look at how that's working.. I had about 12 lines of css before to get a similar result :)) Excellt. thankyou. Where is .slide-index coming from out of interest? never tried that in my trial and error sessions

Answer (score 1):

`#containingDiv:hover img { }` will affect the img when any of the containing div is hovered over so I would use that if I were you, Ryan's solution will only affect the img if you are hovering over it

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input guys. I tried solution 1, but it didn't work. I think it's because I have a bit of a wierd html setup, it's not as straight forward as a few divs and a few images. If anyone could take a look with firebug or something, and let me know exact codes... I've tried so much, I'm lost with it all now. I don't know if it's my poor css, or if it's just not possible..

It's perfect.... APART from when you hover over the popup description..... the product image dims, when it needs to stay at 1.0 opacity.. I hope you understand.

Comment: Ah sucks, had just got it sorted for you when JOPLO answered, it was just a matter of changing the name of the div ID/class. Ah well, glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the opacity on the images when the user is not hovering.

```
divName img {
 opacity:0.3;
 filter:alpha(opacity=30);(IE)
}
```

And then when they hover (this should include your product info styling to as you have that displayed when hovering.)

```
diveName img:hover{
 opacity:1.0;
 filter:alpha(opacity=100);(IE)
}
```

**Also throw in an active class on start so that at least one product is being shown when the page loads**

For example:

```
divName img .activeLoad{
 opacity:1.0;
 filter:alpha(opacity=100);(IE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your styles this declaration

```
.slide-index:hover img{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

As other `div`s are also in the `slide-index` container - the `hover` effect will still be applied.